# ROI transparent background (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, mask, transparent, roi

I'm trying to use imfreehand and save the coordinates of my ROI so when I overlay the image onto another, that ROI is transparent (or set to NAN). Basically is there a way to set inside the imfreehand region as 'NaN' when I overlay onto another image? Reference attached image.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
%% output arrival_time parametric heatmap %%
figure;imagesc(at);colorbar;title('arrival time');
colormap('jet');caxis([2.5 5]);
%savefig(['Acute_1e13_draft_DRAFT_ignore' '.fig']);


%% code to blend heatmap %%
minv = 2.5;%min(min(R1_perf(:,:,29)));
maxv = 5;%max(max(R1_perf(:,:,2 t9)));
map=colormap('jet');
ncol = size(map,1);
s = round(1+(ncol-1)*(at-minv)/(maxv-minv)); % Taking arrival time values and rounding differences
rgb_at = ind2rgb(s,map);
rgb_at = imresize(rgb_at,5);
rgb_perf = ind2rgb(s,map);
rgb_perf = imresize(rgb_perf,5);
rgb_at_scale  = imresize(rgb_at,[100 350],'nearest');
%rgb_at_scale_2  = imresize(rgb_at,[170 220],'nearest');
toto          = zeros(size(rgb_at_scale));
%toto_2          = zeros(size(rgb_at_scale_2));
%toto(190:293,100:455,:) = rgb_at;
alpha = 0.65;
rgb_blend = fliplr(alpha * rgb_at_scale + (1 - alpha) * toto);
hFH = imfreehand();
% Create a binary image ("mask") from the ROI object.
binaryImage = hFH.createMask();
xy = hFH.getPosition;
structBoundaries = bwboundaries(binaryImage);
xy=structBoundaries{1}; % Get n by 2 array of x,y coordinates.
x = xy(:, 2); % Columns.
y = xy(:, 1); % Rows.
hold on; % Don't blow away the image.
plot(x, y, 'LineWidth', 2);
drawnow; % Force it to draw immediately.

% Burn line into image by setting it to 255 wherever the mask is true.
burnedImage = figure;
burnedImage(binaryImage) = nan;
imshow(burnedImage);
axis on;[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: I want to make inside the imfreehand region transparent when I overlay onto another image. I don't know how to do that other than going into the 19x31 array of values and manually changing the values to NaN. Sorry if my questions was unclear, i'll change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that you want to use imfreehand to draw the ROIs then use following code.

```
I = imread('pout.tif');
imshow(I)

% Draw the ROI and double click when finished
h = imfreehand();
position = wait(h);
map = createMask(h);

% set image points within the ROI to NaN
I(map) = nan;

imshow(I)
```

If you want a more generalised method I suggest you try the code below. It calculates which image points are within the polygon defined by x and y. If you are interested you can read about the equations used following this [link](http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/PointsInOut/PointInOut_.htm).

```
I = imread('eight.tif');

% Get subscripts
[py, px] = meshgrid(1:size(I,1), 1:size(I,2));

% Coordinates defining the region
x = [222 272 300 270 221 194];
y = [21 21 75 121 121 75];

% Display the region
figure
imagesc(I)
hold on
fill(x,y,'r')
hold off

% Close the loop of the polygon
x = [x,x(1)];
y = [y,y(1)];

n = numel(x);
k = zeros([size(px),n-1]);

% See link for explanation
for i=1:n-1
    k(:,:,i) = (px - x(i))*(y(i+1) - y(i)) - (py - y(i))*(x(i+1) - x(i));
end
map = all(k > 0,3) | all(k < 0,3);

% Set image points within the ROI to NaN
I(map') = nan;

% Display the final result
figure
imagesc(I)
```

Comment: The only reason why I use freehand is because the ROI size and shape changes for each image. Also, this is set as a .fig file and then I overlay the image on top of a greyscale image, I don't know if that was clear before. I will try out both methods, appreciate the help.